# Smalltalk Matrix nil error

Tags: matrix, smalltalk

So im running this code in playground of pharos 6.0 and it gives me an error saying "unindex object is not access able. Basically, I'm trying to make a matrix that is 8x10. How do I make one?

```
  | aMatrix row col|


  aMatrix := Matrix new.
  aMatrix numberOfColumns: 3.
  aMatrix numberOfRows: 3. 
  aMatrix at: 2 at: 2 put: 6.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to make a matrix 8x10 why do you do

```
aMatrix numberOfColumns: 3.
aMatrix numberOfRows: 3.
```

?

I checked the code, and I don't get why it is implemented the way it is implemented. `numberOfColumns:` and `numberOfRows:` just assign the parameter to an instance variable, but don't change the internal data structure.

You should do something like:

```
aMatrix := Matrix rows: 8 columns: 10.   
aMatrix at: 2 at: 2 put: 6.
```

Comment: hey, thanks for helping me. How would I print this matrix through write stream?